# How to implement drop and release effect in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to implement the following effect, I thought I would be able do it by using css, like: background-attachment, or some scroll, but without any luck. Should I have to do it via drop events? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I implemented using dragula, see here: http://jsbin.com/cudulup/edit?html,css,js,output. But there are 2 issues: firstly, it happened for X and Y axises, but the requirements is only on Y axis. Secondly,  I missed the transition effect. Anyone could help?